# Unknown characters at the end of the word

Tags: mysql, r, encoding

I am pulling data from database into R. I use the following commands to do this:

```
drv = dbDriver("MySQL")
con = dbConnect(drv,<credentials>)
dbSendQuery(con,"SET character_set_results = utf8;")
<code to pull data>
```

The data is stored in **UTF-8** encoding in the database.I pull a dataframe with a column containing words. Once i pull the data, i convert the encoding to **ASCII//TRANSLIT** using `iconv(x,"UTF-8","ASCII//TRANSLIT")` Everything is working fine except that for few words i see an extra character appearing after i change the encoding. For example when u look in database you see `abc` and when u import, you get `abc`. But once you change the encoding to **ASCII//TRANSLIT** this word changes to `abc?`. I used https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter to check for encoding. I copied word **abc** in first box named unicode text and i see **abcâ¬** in box named utf-8 text.What are these special characters and how to use them in regex to filter these out?

Answer (score 0):

`SET character_set_results = utf8` is probably not sufficient.  Change to `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

What do you mean by "pull the data"?  Is it put into a database table?  If so, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

To investigate strange characters, do `SELECT HEX(...) ...` to see what is actually there.  From that, we might be able to deduce what happened.

It looks like `â¬` is part of the Mojibake for one of these.
    ⬀,⬁,⬂,⬃,⬄,⬅,⬆,⬇,⬈,⬉,⬊,⬋,⬌,⬍,⬎,⬏,⬐,⬑,⬒,⬓,⬔,⬕,⬖,⬗,⬘,⬙,⬚,⬛,⬜,⬝,⬞,⬟,⬠,⬡,⬢,⬣,⬤,⬥,⬦,⬧,⬨,⬩,⬪,⬫,⬬,⬭,⬮,⬯,⬰,⬱,⬲,⬳,⬴,⬵,⬶,⬷,⬸,⬹,⬺,⬻,⬼,⬽,⬾,⬿

```
â¬, when treated as latin1,        is hex E2AC
⬀ when treated as UTF-8 (utf8mb4), is hex E2AC80
⬁                                  is hex E2AC81,
etc
```

The causes of Mojibake are discussed [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored).

Instead of trying to filter them out, you should fix the code to preserve them.